# AFNetworking 2.0 with OAuth2 tokens

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, afnetworking-2

I am trying to find a way to use `OAuth2` (access and refresh tokens) with `AFNetworking`. I'm having a hard time finding good documentation bout it.

I know about the `AFOAuth2Client` project, but that only works for `AFNetworking` `1.x`. Are there any good solutions for `AFNetworking` `2.0`?

Also, how exactly will the tokens be refreshed? Am I supposed to always check for token expiry for every request? Where exactly can this be done? Or maybe use a timer for when the token expires, then fetch a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a branch of a `AFOAuth2Client` with support of `AFNetworking 2.0`. Have a look at this discussion:

> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55#commits-pushed-5ed7a6e

These fixes allow the library to work with `AFNetworking 2.0`. There are even instruction on how to reference it when using a CocoaPods.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But how about refreshing the access token? Is that handled by the library? If not, then it looks like I would have to check for token expiry for every request being made, unless there is another better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

To address your question about token refresh, below is the code I've used on my last couple of projects to check and refresh the token, if needed, on each request.

Basically, it is just passing the request block to a method to make the token check and then running the block immediately if the token is good or after the token is refreshed.

```
- (void)refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess:(APIClientSuccess)success
                              failure:(APIClientFailure)failure {
    if (self.credential == nil) {
        if (failure) {
            // Failed to get credentials
        }
        return;
    }
    if (!self.credential.isExpired) {
        if (success) {
            success(nil, nil);
        }
        return;
    }
    [self authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:kOAuthURL
                            refreshToken:self.credential.refreshToken
                                 success:^(AFOAuthCredential *newCredential) {
                                     // SUCCESS!
                                     self.credential = newCredential;
                                     if (success) {
                                         success(nil, nil);
                                     }
                                 }
                                 failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                     // Failed to get credentials
                                     if (failure) {
                                         failure(nil, error);
                                     }
                                 }];
}
- (void)RefreshGET:(NSString *)URLString
 parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
    success:(APIClientSuccess)success
    failure:(APIClientFailure)failure
{
    APIClientSuccess nestedSuccess  = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *thisRequestOperation = [super GET:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if (success) {
                success((AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation, responseObject);
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // Failed request
            if (failure) {
                failure((AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation, error);
            }
        }];
    };
    [self refreshAccessTokenWithSuccess:nestedSuccess failure:failure];
}
```

Let me know if you would like to see the whole APIClient class.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for, but this is how my company has handled it. We use a API for our project so we hand over the GMail OAuth information to our API then it returns us a token for the API. We let the API handle the token/expiring tokens.

Depending on your application, that can work really well. We tried your approach at first and it was too much to handle in our minds on device, so we integrated it into our API. All I have to do on device is add a X-Authorization header with our API token which never changes.

May not be the answer you want, just at least an alternative route from someone who has been in your shoes.

Answer (score 0):

I forked a pretty awesome AFOAuth2Client rewrite (by Gabriel Rinaldi) for AFNetworking 2.0 and made a couple of changes to suit my needs (expose the responseObject and accept invalid SSL certs). Currently pending a pull request (tho they're not that commonplace so I don't expect them to be accepted). You can get my version via [GitHub](https://github.com/nicktmro/GROAuth2SessionManager)

or Cocoapods

`pod 'GROAuth2Client', :git => 'https://github.com/nicktmro/GROAuth2SessionManager'`

or you can just go to Gabriel's original repo and add that as a pod `pod "GROAuth2SessionManager" , "~> 0.2"`.

I realise this is not answering the second part of your question regarding the refresh of the token. I am not that far in my project yet so I cannot tell you for sure but I guess you can find out pretty quickly if it refreshes it or not.